# Orthogonal matrix pairs connected by rescaling of rows and columns

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, orthogonal-matrices

For which choices of column-orthogonal matrix $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and real diagonal matrices $\Lambda_0$ and $\Lambda_1$ (different from the identity) does it hold that
$$
O=\Lambda_0U\Lambda_1
$$
is also column-orthogonal? Equivalently, what solutions are there to the above matrix equation where $O$ and $U$ are column-orthogonal.

Comment: $\Lambda_i$ are at least invertible?

Comment: @Exodd Sure, that must be true, but for a set of $\Lambda_i$ and a choice of $U$, not all resulting $O$ matrices will be orthogonal. There must be some extra conditions on $U$ (and $O$ be extension)
edit: rephrased question to make it more clear that we want to "solve" for both $U$ and $\Lambda$.

Comment: If $\Lambda_1$ is invertible, then $U\Lambda_1$ is always orthogonal

Comment: @Exodd Right, but that won't be true for arbitrary $\Lambda_0$, no? Ideally, $U$ and $O$ should be orthonormal, and not just orthogonal, but I take it $\Lambda_1$ can be set to scale the columns appropriately.
So the more general question might be to solve $O=\Lambda_0 U$ for $O$ and $U$ column-orthogonal and $\Lambda_0$ diagonal.